# "Only numeric data" error on logs-base metric GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging, google-cloud-monitoring

I have use Ops agent to send log to Cloud Logging
[Uploaded logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgzIZ.png)
And then I used these logs to create logs-base metric with field name is `jsonPayload.data`
[Create logs-base metric](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blF6s.png)
After that, I review logs of that metric to make sure input data is correct
[Review input data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QLjE.png)
But finally, the result is Cloud metric show error `Only numeric data can be drawn as a line chart`. I have checked at "review logs" step and make sure that input data is numeric. Can anyone help me explain that?
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXJPG.png)

Sorry, I'm new to stackoverflow, so I can't upload image directly.

Comment: I am also getting the same error. It is happening only for "Distribution" type Metric. "Counter" type metric is plotted without any issue.

Comment: I get this error when I use`max` or `min` as a `Group by` function with log-based metrics. Does any understand why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see the Metric by changing the aligner to percentile.
[image]